# CASE Statement Issue With Operators

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, operators, case

I have a CASE statement that I am hung up on. It is just a simple statement, but with `>` and `<` operators. It is not letting me use those in the logic. Here is my statement :

```
case DATEDIFF(d, date1, GETDATE()) - (DATEDIFF(ww, date2, GetDate()) * 2)
when 1 Then 'Now'
when > 1 Then 'After'
when < 1 Then 'Tomorrow'
else 'N/A' end AS 'Status'
```

It is giving me an error on the `<` and `>` line, are you not able to use those in CASE statements?

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
DATEDIFF(d, date1, GETDATE()) - (DATEDIFF(ww, date2, GetDate()) * 2)
```

actually needs to be in every `when` comparison.

There's probably a way to make it more concise, but if you use this, it should work.

```
    case 
    when (DATEDIFF(d, date1, GETDATE()) - (DATEDIFF(ww, date2, GetDate()) * 2)) = 1 Then 'Now'
    when (DATEDIFF(d, date1, GETDATE()) - (DATEDIFF(ww, date2, GetDate()) * 2)) > 1 Then 'After'
    when (DATEDIFF(d, date1, GETDATE()) - (DATEDIFF(ww, date2, GetDate()) * 2)) < 1 Then 'Tomorrow'
    else 'N/A' 
    end AS 'Status'
```

Answer (score 1):

The "short hand" notation that you're using works **only** with equality - if you need to use other operators, you need to include the value expression in the `WHEN` clause:

```
case 
   when DATEDIFF(d, date1, GETDATE()) - (DATEDIFF(ww, date2, GetDate()) * 2) = 1 Then 'Now'
   when DATEDIFF(d, date1, GETDATE()) - (DATEDIFF(ww, date2, GetDate()) * 2) > 1 Then 'After'
   when DATEDIFF(d, date1, GETDATE()) - (DATEDIFF(ww, date2, GetDate()) * 2) < 1 Then 'Tomorrow'
   else 'N/A' 
end AS 'Status'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [searched CASE expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). You can do something like this:

```
;WITH DATA(Val) AS
(
    SELECT DATEDIFF(d, date1, GETDATE()) - (DATEDIFF(ww, date2, GetDate()) * 2)
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT CASE WHEN Val = 1 THEN 'Now' 
            WHEN Val > 1 THEN 'After'
            WHEN Val < 1 THEN 'Tomorrow'
            ELSE 'N/A' END AS Val
FROM DATA;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do data math three times, use the `SIGN` function instead:

```
select case sign(DATEDIFF(d, date1, GETDATE()) - (DATEDIFF(ww, date2, GetDate()) * 2))
when 0 Then 'Now'
when 1 Then 'After'
when -1 Then 'Tomorrow'
else 'N/A' end AS Status
```

Answer (score 0):

your code would word in a JAVA environment but in SQL you have to specify the operand in your case statement. Either define it in a variable, such as @myDate = GETDATE() or use the function in the case: 
WHEN (DATEDIFF(d, date1, GETDATE()) - (DATEDIFF(ww, date2, GetDate()) * 2) THEN ...